# Finding matches between columns and within rows in R

Tags: r, string, match

I am working with two columns of zip code data. One column represents search location and the second column represents structure location(s). I am trying to find when there is a match between the search zip code and the structure zip code. While the search zip code will always only be one zip code, the structure may have a number of different zip codes associated with it, and this number varies with each search.

I have tried filter(df, zip1 == zip2), but this only matches when there is an exact match and only 1 location zip in the zip2 column. similarly I have tried %in% but this doesn't limit the matches within rows. I have also tried breaking Zip2 into 1 distinct column for every zip code associated with a location, but I failed here too because the number of locations can vary from 1-300. I am still very much an R beginner, and so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you for the quick responses. In order to improve my question Here is some sample data that would illustrate my problem (just a slight modification of @r2evans response).

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  searchzip    = c(11111, 22222, 33333, 44444),
  structurezip = c(111112222233333, 222234444, 3333533333, 44446))
```

In this case, I would have matches on the first row and the 3rd row but not the others.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: `grep` or `grepl` may help but let's see some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to first form a frame that pairs a zip with one or more matching zips, then `merge` it in.

Sample data:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  searchzip    = c(11111, 22222, 33333, 44444),
  structurezip = c(11111, 22223, 33335, 44446))
zipmatch <- data.frame(
  zip1 = c(11111, 11111, 22222, 22222, 33333, 33333, 33333, 44444, 44444),
  zip2 = c(11111, 11112, 22222, 22223, 33333, 33334, 33335, 44444, 44445),
  ismatch = TRUE)
```

The merge and its results:

```r
df1new <- merge(
  df1, zipmatch,
  by.x = c("searchzip", "structurezip"),
  by.y = c("zip1", "zip2"), all.x = TRUE)
df1new
#   searchzip structurezip ismatch
# 1     11111        11111    TRUE
# 2     22222        22223    TRUE
# 3     33333        33335    TRUE
# 4     44444        44446      NA
```

(When you're comfortable that this is doing what you want, then you can just overwrite `df1` directly instead of using a new variable `df1new`.) In this case, the merge operation will give you `TRUE` for known matches and fill the non-matched rows with `NA`, so we can simply replace this with

```r
df1new$ismatch <- !is.na(df1new$ismatch)
df1new
#   searchzip structurezip ismatch
# 1     11111        11111    TRUE
# 2     22222        22223    TRUE
# 3     33333        33335    TRUE
# 4     44444        44446   FALSE
```

---

In `dplyr`-speak:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  left_join(zipmatch, by = c("searchzip" = "zip1", "structurezip" = "zip2")) %>%
  mutate(ismatch = !is.na(ismatch))
#   searchzip structurezip ismatch
# 1     11111        11111    TRUE
# 2     22222        22223    TRUE
# 3     33333        33335    TRUE
# 4     44444        44446   FALSE
```

Comment: OP said "I have also tried breaking Zip2 into 1 distinct column for every zip code associated with a location, but I failed here too because the number of locations can vary from 1-300. " which leads me to believe the zip2 looks more like c("11111,11112", "22222,33333,44444") and needs to be de-stacked first

Comment: Yes, that's entirely likely given your interpretation. Having sample data will clear that up.